# Is there a Cadence metric that shows how many activities are waiting to be executed in a task list?

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I'm trying to find a Cadence metric that shows how many activities are waiting to be executed in a task list. Is there such a metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no a metric exactly like that. There have been several users asking for it but the architecture has made it [difficult](https://github.com/uber/cadence/issues/4857) to support that.

Depends on what you really need, there are different approaches:

- If you want to know if a task list is overloaded so that you can scale up worker fleet or tasklist partition, you should look at `schedule_to_start_latency` on client metrics, or `sync_match_latency` on server metrics.
- If you simply want to know if a tasklist is idle or not, you can just look at `poll_no_task` on client metrics